# vector.size() returns a bigger result than the number of elements of the vector variable

Tags: c++

Hello I trying to solve a problem of leetcode, and I'm using the vector.size() method to iterate over the vector variable, but it returns a bigger number than the number of elements. It returns 40 when the actual number of elements is 4. Also when compiled the program will stop with a "Debug Assertion Failed" error. 
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


std::vector<int> twoSum(std::vector<int>& nums, int target) {

int num01 = 0;
int num02 = 0;
int result = 0;

int indice01 = 0;
int indice02 = 0;
std::vector<int> solution = {0,0};


std::cout << "inside twoSum" << std::endl;
std::cout << "nums.size is: "<< nums.size() << result << std::endl;


for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {



    for (int j = 0; j < nums.size(); j++) {

        num01 = nums[i];
        num01 = nums[j];

        indice01 = i;

        indice02 = j;



        result = num01 + num02;
        std::cout << "result is: " << result << std::endl;


        if (result == target) {


            solution[0] = indice01;
            solution[1] = indice02;

            std::cout << "solution is: " << solution[0] << " y " << solution[1] << result << 
            std::endl;


            return solution;

        }



    }


}


}

int main() {

std::cout << "hola mundo" << std::endl;


std::vector<int> numeros = {2,7,11,15};



int objetivo = 9;

std::vector<int> resultado = twoSum(numeros, objetivo);

std::cout << "la solucion es: " << resultado[0] << " y " << resultado[1] << std::endl;




return 0;

}
```

Comment: Compiler warnings should say there's no return in every case in your function (life of new programmers would be much easier if all warnings were errors by default).

Comment: Look at `nums.size() << result << std::endl;` until you see what's happening. (Hint: "40" looks exactly the same as "4" and "0" put next to each other.) The cause of the crash is hinted at by @MichaelChourdakis, and has nothing to do with the size.

Comment: *Also when compiled the program will stop with a "Debug Assertion Failed" error*. The debugger will likely give you the option of inspecting the state of the program at this point. Take it up on the offer, gather information about the crash, and use the gathered information to narrow down the possibilities. If this doesn't allow you to narrow the possibilities down to one and solve that one possibility, update the question with the gathered information.